# Passing Mongo Documents in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, modal-dialog, popover

I have a question as to how I can pass my Mongo documents around my JS and HTML. I have an example below, I'm trying to have my popover display the name of the thumbnail that's being hovered over. When someone clicks on the thumbnail a modal pops up that displays the picture as well as the description of the thumbnail. The issue is that when I try to pass the this.name element to the popover, it displays the name of the first thumbnail i hover over for all of the thumbnails, but it doesnt use the information for the first thumbnail on all the modals (its actually dynamic). I want to know what I'm doing wrong, the only work around I've found is to put the {{name}} tag inside my actual html as the data-content to the thumbnail.

HTML

```
<template name="gallery">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-content='{{name}}'>
        <img src="{{img}}" alt="...">
          <div class="caption">
            <h5><center>{{name}}</center></h5>
          </div>
      </a>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
Gallerys = new Mongo.Collection("gallerys");

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.body.helpers({
    gallerys: function () {
      return Gallerys.find({}, {sort: {createdAt  :-1}});
    }
  });

  Template.body.events({
    "mouseover a.thumbnail" :function(event, template){
      $('a.thumbnail').popover({
        trigger: "hover",
        placement: "bottom",
        })
    },
    "click a.thumbnail": function(event, template) {
      event.preventDefault();
      bootbox.dialog({
        title: '<center><h2>'+ this.name.toUpperCase() +'</h2></center>',
        message: '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-3"><img class="img-rounded" height="200" width="200" src="' + this.img + '"></div><div class="col-md-9"><h4>Description</h4>"'+ this.description +'"</div></div>',
        size: 'large',
        buttons: {
          play:{
            label:'PLAY SAMPLE <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>',
            className:"btn-success pull-left modalbtn"
          },
          download: {
            label:'DOWNLOAD <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>',
            className:"btn-primary modalbtn",
            callback: function() {}
          }
        },
        onEscape: function() {},
        });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you do the events on `Template.gallery` rather than `Template.body` ?

Comment: Yes the code isn't very organized right now, but I just want to get the concepts down before organizing everything. I don't think changing to Template.gallery is going to do much as of now. I want to know how I can pass around these elements.

Answer (score 0):

Like BraveKenny already suggested, move the helper event to the Template.gallery. It isn't an optional/cosmetic step to beautify your code. It sets the correct data context in the event helper.

---

Here is a boilerplate app showing the way data context work:

http://meteorpad.com/pad/hPaJ35NnWyHjkWAD3/Leaderboard

Comment: I tried changing from Template.body to Template.gallery, but it's still only showing one name for all of the gallery thumbnails when i hover when i set the data-context to this.name. Any ideas?

Comment: Just some clarification also, the gallery template is inside of the body, so i'm not sure if targeting the template will change anything, would like to know more if possible